# How to tell what are the mandatory parameters when calling an AngularJS $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I know that is it possible to create custom methods using the AngularJs $resource, but **I would like to know if it is possible to tell the person that is using the resource what parameter they should provide when calling it**.

I am not talking about default values, but more like a guideline of what to provide to call the $resource.

```
$resource("/api/myEntity/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
    getBySlug: {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/MyEntity/GetBySlug/"
        //something like : paramsToProvide : {slug : "", etc.}
    },
});

//...

myEntity.myCustomMethod({}, function(){
    //callback...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory which exposes an API, and throw an error or log a warning if a function is called without required parameters.

```
var myEntity = $resource(...);

return {
   getBySlug: function getBySlug(slug) {
      if (slug === undefined) {
         throw new Error('Please provide a slug');
      }
      return myEntity.getBySlug({slug: slug}).$promise;
   }
};
```

Comment: This would remove all the $save, $get, $query and $delete methods from a default $resource, so I don't think that would be a viable option.